StateStoreBuilders as @Beans result in 'Invalid topology: StateStore store is not added yet.'
According to https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/reference/kafka/kafka-streams-binder/state-store.html the declaration and usage of StateStoreBuilder @Beans should be as follows:
    @Bean
    fun store() = Stores.keyValueStoreBuilder(
        Stores.persistentKeyValueStore("store"),
        Serdes.Integer(),
        Serdes.Integer()
    )

    @Bean
    fun consumer() =
        Consumer { events: KStream<Int, Int> ->
            events
                .process(ProcessorSupplier { CustomProcessor() }, "store")
        }

class CustomProcessor : Processor<Int, Int, Int, Int> {
    private lateinit var context: ProcessorContext<Int, Int>
    private lateinit var store: KeyValueStore<Int, Int>

    override fun init(context: ProcessorContext<Int, Int>) {
        this.context = context
        store = context.getStateStore("store")
    }

    override fun process(record: Record<Int, Int>) {
        context.forward(record)
    }
}

I still get the following error:
org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.TopologyException: Invalid topology: StateStore store is not added yet.

It's worth mentioning that I use TestDriver and not EmbeddedKafka in the integration test:
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension::class)
@SpringBootTest(
    webEnvironment = RANDOM_PORT,
    properties = ["spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true"]
)
@Import(TestChannelBinderConfiguration::class)
@TestPropertySource(properties = ["spring.cloud.function.definition=none"])
@TestConstructor(autowireMode = ALL)
class IntegrationTest(
    private val consumer: Consumer<KStream<Int, Int>>,
    protected var testDriver: TopologyTestDriver,
    protected val kafkaStreamsBinderConfigurationProperties: KafkaStreamsBinderConfigurationProperties
) {
    @Test
    fun test() {
        setupTestDriver { 
            consumer.accept(it.stream("input-topic"))
        }
    }
    
    protected open fun setupTestDriver(streamCreator: (StreamsBuilder) -> Unit) {
        val properties = Properties().apply {
            putAll(kafkaStreamsBinderConfigurationProperties.configuration)
            putIfAbsent(BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "dummy-bootstrap-host:0")
            putIfAbsent(
                APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG,
                "dummy-topology-test-driver-app-id-" + ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt()
            )
        }
        val streamsConfig = StreamsConfig(properties)
        val topologyConfig = TopologyConfig(streamsConfig)
        val streamsBuilder = StreamsBuilder(topologyConfig)
        streamCreator(streamsBuilder)
        val topology = streamsBuilder.build(properties)
        testDriver = TopologyTestDriver(topology, properties)

    }
}


Which version of the binder that you are using? Any chance you can manually update the spring-kafka version to 3.2.0-SNAPSHOT or RC1. Note: for this, you need to use Spring Boot 3.3.0 and kafka client 3.7.0 etc. We recently made some changes to how topologies are created in spring-kafka which might be related to the issue that you are seeing. That change also was driven by some requirements from testing with TopologyDriver.
